# Parametric quadratic equation in Q(a)

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

Are there any algebraic numbers $a$ with the following property: for all $q\in\mathbb{Q}$, the square roots of $a+q$ are in $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ ?

I`m fairly certain that the answer is **no**, but how does one prove that (preferably with elementary methods, not advanced galois theory)?

For example, if $a$ is real, then it is trivial: take $q$ such that $a+q<0$, and the square roots are not real, whereas $\mathbb{Q}(a)\subset \mathbb{R}$. I have been unable to find a similar reasoning for the general case.